# How to initially hide the Show/Hide columns button in material react table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, material-react-table

How can I initially hide the "Show/Hide columns" button in material-react-table?

[image: show/hide column button]

I searched through the documentation but couldn't find any information on how to hide this button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to custome top toolbar. Here is [the example](https://github.com/KevinVandy/material-react-table/blob/main/apps/material-react-table-docs/examples/custom-top-toolbar/sandbox/src/TS.tsx#L44).

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the column hiding button from the top toolbar by setting the [`enableHiding`](https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/column-hiding#relevant-props) prop to `false` in Material React Table.

**Example:**

```
<MaterialReactTable
  columns={columns}
  data={data}
  enableHiding={false}
/>
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Working CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dreamy-browser-s8893s?file=%2Fsrc%2FTS.tsx%3A106%2C36

Comment: Ah yes you right. Thank you.
Due to my simultaneous use of 'enableColumnOrdering', the option 'enableHiding={false}' did not function as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all of the default toolbar buttons using these settings.

```
enableHiding: false,
enableGlobalFilter: false,
enableFullScreenToggle: false,
enableDensityToggle: false,
enableFilters: false
```

The docs don't cover these settings unfortunately, if you choose to hide the toolbar entirely you will lose access to certain features such as the top of table progress bar.